# Install Ubuntu partitions

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gparted

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop on which windows 8.1 is installed. I have read in some sites that I have to use Gparted or similar tools, but there are also sites that don´t this kind of tools, just shrink the volume of C:.
What is the difference between using Gparted or similar and not using it, to install Ubuntu for dual boot.

Comment: `GParted` is used to partition your `HD`. Any other tool may work, depending on whether that tool can partition your HD to `ext3` or `ext4` for `Ubuntu`. I have used `GParted` to dual boot my PC to operate `Ubuntu` and `Windows` and it works pretty well. I am not familiar with other programs out there that repartition but I would assume they perform the same task as `GParted`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I really want to know is if it´s compulsory to use a tool like GParted or I can avoid this step. I mean, can I just shrink C: drive and then when I install Ubuntu create the /, /home and swap prtitions over the free space?  Some sites like this:http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html do not mention it, why?

Comment: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-8-ubuntu.html here's a good tutorial. GParted seems recommended.

Comment: I dont think shrinking will work because you still need to format the partition/drive to ext2 or ext3. You can use the same filesystem (NTFS), but that requires another tool to do so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/85695) on Ask Ubuntu. As for the difference, `gparted` and similar tools help you partition your hard drive. The Ubuntu installer can also do this automatically which is, presumably, the way suggested by the sites you read.

I would not do that though and especially not with a system that has windowd8 installed since there are other complications. You would be much safer creating the partition yourself and then telling the Ubuntu installer to install to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My english is not good and I do not understand well what you mean. Do you recommend me to use GParted, right? What are the benefits of using a tool like this and not using it?

Comment: @user3776671 the benefits are that you can make sure that the system is set up the way you want it and it is safer to do it manually than trust the installer to do it for you. `gparted` just splits your hard drive into separate 'partitions' so you can resize the windows partition yourself and add Ubuntu to the remaining space. Otherwise, the installer tries to automatically guess what should be done and that could cause problems.